# Do cryptonight hash speeds mirror scrypt and SHA-256 hash speeds?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-hardware, hashrate-comparison

There are various websites that tabulate SHA-256 & scrypt hash speeds of various hardware. I wonder how these correspond to crytonight hash speeds. Are they correlated? Or does the correlation break depending on chip architecture?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is strictly no correlation between the hash speed of different hashing algorithms.

I guess it can possibly make sense for hardware that are capable of dual mining.

But, currently, hardware for SHA-256 & scrypt are [ASICs](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/12042/41820), so they [won't work for others hashing algorithms](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/19766/41820)

Comment: Good point, I meant a general processor crunching the different algorithms.

Comment: One of the most significant factor for monero mining is the L3 cache size. Unfortunately, i was not aware of btc when it was cpu mined :) , but i don't think that's the case.

Comment: most significant factor currently seems to be integrated AES instructions on the CPU https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set